# How can I reset the file name on a asp:FileUpload after I hit the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload section on my asp.net site:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"/>

<asp:Button ID="UploadPrework" runat="server" OnClick="UploadPrework" Text="Upload" />
```

In my backend when someone hits the upload button I save the file:

```
    protected void UploadPrework(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            ReadExcelSheet();
        }

    }

    private void ReadExcelSheet()
    {
        String savePath = FileUpload1.FileName;

        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + savePath));

    }
```

However, the name of the file in the textbox disappears after the file is saved. Instead, it goes back to saying "no file chosen".

How can I reset my filename?

I've tried doing this without any luck:

```
FileUpload1.FileName = savePath;
```

Comment: I know this is because of the autopostback but surely there must be a workaround

Answer (score 0):

This isn't settable programatically by design.  The file upload control renders as

```
<input type="file" ... />
```

Which most browsers disallow presetting as a security precaution where a malicious user could potentially set the value attribute to c:\passwords.txt, hide the control via css and submit the form via javascript.

You can verify this behavior via the console in Chrome (IE just seems to ignore the attempt):

`>>$("#MainContent_FileUpload1").val("test.txt")`

`>>InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`